# url.openConnection().getInputStream() does not seem to connect to php

Tags: java, php, android, url

I am writing an app for android, this part of the app works like a lite weight RSS feed reader. I got the initial code from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=Lnan_DJU7DI). I modified the code to suit my scenario and it did not work. I then just copied the original code verbatim and there were a small number of changes needed for the new version of android studio. then code does run. changing the url to the url I need produces a 404. yes, yes I know the xml format is different but the program never makes it that far anyway. the original url is "https://feeds.news24.com/articles/fin24/tech/rss". the new url is "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0". the 404 comes up on the line, "return url.openConnection().getInputStream();". Maybe there is another method I need to use to get php? I have tried other pages that are not php and they work as expected. the issue comes up when I try to use php pages, that happens to be php. The php page works fine in all of my browsers. I have tried to see if anyone else has encountered this problem but I was not able find anything specific. I am not a php programmer so I am not sure as to why this issue would pop up. I would appreciate any incite and thank you in advance.

Here is the full code if anyone wants to see it.

```
package com.ledorianindustries.simplerss;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lvRss;
ArrayList<String> titles;
ArrayList<String> links;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvRss = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRss);

    titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    links = new ArrayList<String>();

    lvRss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    new ProcessInBackground().execute();
}

public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
{
    try
    {
        //openConnection() returns instance that represents a connection to the remote object referred to by the URL
        //getInputStream() returns a stream that reads from the open connection
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Exception>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    Exception exception = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Busy loading rss feed...please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try
        {
            //URL url = new URL("https://feeds.news24.com/articles/fin24/tech/rss");
            URL url = new URL ( "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0" );
            //creates new instance of PullParserFactory that can be used to create XML pull parsers
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

            //Specifies whether the parser produced by this factory will provide support
            //for XML namespaces
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

            //creates a new instance of a XML pull parser using the currently configured
            //factory features
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

            /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
             * We should take into consideration that the rss feed name is also enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
             * Every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title> etc."
             * We should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
             * and take into consideration only the "<title>" tag which is a child of the "<item>" tag
             *
             * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable called "insideItem".
             */
            boolean insideItem = false;

            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, START_DOCUMENT, END_DOCUMENT etc..
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType(); //loop control variable

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                //if we are at a START_TAG (opening tag)
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {
                    //if the tag is called "item"
                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        insideItem = true;
                    }
                    //if the tag is called "title"
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                    {
                        if (insideItem)
                        {
                            // extract the text between <title> and </title>
                            titles.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }
                    //if the tag is called "link"
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                    {
                        if (insideItem)
                        {
                            // extract the text between <link> and </link>
                            links.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }
                }
                //if we are at an END_TAG and the END_TAG is called "item"
                else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                {
                    insideItem = false;
                }

                eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
            }


        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return exception;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);

        lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);


        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Uri.parse(links.get(position)) ?? What is links.get(position)? How should we ever know? Why are you posting that code? Is it relevant?

Comment: @blackapps is it relevant? yes. that comes from the user clicking in the list view... the position is the position in the list view clicked by the user. Also that part of the code does not get processed in the scenario of using the php. Also that link opens that link in the RSS feed.

Comment: `the position is the position in the list view clicked by the user` You dont have to tell that. Everybody sees that. You better had told the link/url as now nobody knows the url/link. That i was asking!

Comment: the specific link comes from the web page xml data.

Comment: Irrelevant. You should post the link if you come here for help. Only then we can check your code.

Comment: I don't think you understand. A. the data in the RSS feed is dynamic and constantly changing. B. it literally does not matter because the point in the code that your are hung up on does not get processed.

Comment: Oh, and I did post the link in the original post... "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0"

Comment: We don t know that it is that view. So you better write Uri.parse(`"https://aler......"`) as then we see what you do. And now we are eleven hours further...